# Why is this array chunk not working as expected causing a circular array errr

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve some interview questions in preparation for an interview. I tried to come up with a solution for "chunking" an array. Here's the toy problem along with my solution. I seem to be getting an error but when I follow my logic, it all works fine:

```
// --- Directions
// Given an array and chunk size, divide the array into many subarrays
// where each subarray is of length size
// --- Examples
chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4]]


chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3); //  --> [[ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4); // --> [[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [5]]

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10); // --> [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

```js
// --- Directions
// Given an array and chunk size, divide the array into many subarrays
// where each subarray is of length size
// --- Examples
/* 
chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3); //  --> [[ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4); // --> [[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [5]]

chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10); // --> [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
 */
function chunk(array, size) {
    const a = [];
    const final = [];
    const log = console.log;
    for (let item of array) {
        if (a.length === size) {
            final.push(a);
            a.length = 0;
            a.push(item);
        } else if (a.length < size) {
            a.push(item);
        }
    }
    log('final:::::::::', final);
    return final;
}
chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4]]
chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

When I console.log the final array, I get a circular array. So if someone could help explain what a circular array is and if that's the actual error in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you just need to reinitialise array every item, instead of using same array memory location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reinitialise array every item, instead of using same array memory location

```js
function chunk(array, size) {
    let a = [];
    const final = [];
    const log = console.log;
    for (let item of array) {
        if (a.length === size) {
            final.push(a);
            a = [];   // <--- reinitialise array to a new memory location
            a.push(item);
        } else if (a.length < size) {
            a.push(item);
        }
    }
    log('final:::::::::', final);
    return final;
}
chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4]]
chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

```
a.length = 0
```

Doesn't affect the memory location of variable a, it will still point out to same memory location as before, but when you do `a = []` now point to a different memory location all together.

Comment: Thanks! Since this is the answer with an actual explanation, this is being chosen as the best answer. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

you need to recreate the a array

```
    function chunk(array, size) {
        let a = [];
        const final = [];
        const log = console.log;

        for (let item of array) {
            if (a.length === size) {
                final.push(a);
                a = [];
            }
            a.push(item);
        }
        if (a.length > 0) {
            final.push(a)
        }
        log('final:::::::::', final);
        return final;
    }
    chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4]]
    chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2); // --> [[ 1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because the answer here actually appropriately chunks the code. I had a bug in my original question, so this fixes that bug as well. Thanks for your input!